# fast rule out if a member is in a set

Tags: c++, c, performance, algorithm

I have a small group of numbers, which i constantly need to search.

the group is static and known at the begining of time.

I know from observations that most of the time the number i am searching is not in the group.

what I am searching for is an algoroithm that in one or two instructions will:

1. never say a number is not in the group and it is
2. the algorithm most or all of the time predicts if it is

for example,

If the numbers are x,y,z i can do the following:

save:

```
tmp = (x | y | z)
```

when I search for a number i can do:

```
if ((num & tmp) == (num))
    do the real search
```

if the number is x, y or z it is guarantee to return num when doing AND with it.
if it is not I might search for nothing - but thats basically ok.

the main problem with this test is that most of the time for more than 5 numbers in the group i will get TRUE even if num is not in the group.

i was thinking of using XOR magic:

```
tmp = (x ^ y ^ z)
```

and when searching do something like:

```
(num ^ tmp)
```

but i don't see how this can help me to figure if the element is in the group or not.

any ideas ?

Thanks,

Itay

**UPDATE**

What I have found useful is using something like a very simplistic bloom filter:

I've hashed x, y and z to a bit array (for example 8 bits).
then, i have shiftted the results to the correct bits:

```
uint8_t digest = (1 << (x % 8)) | (1 << (y % 8)) | (1 << (z % 8))
```

and on the search function i've used:

```
if ( (1 << (num % 8)) & digest )
```

I did some profiling using random numbers and got that using 8 bits gave me false indications on about 30% of the time.
using 16 bit made it even better.

Comment: You should provide one or more examples of the groups you need to represent, as this can help us find interesting patterns.

Comment: Why don't you use boolean array lookup ? Maybe with some primitive hashing if the range of number is too large.

Comment: Have you considered sorting the list with eg `qsort` and then using `bsearch` to search?  Your bitwise arithmetic is a cool idea but as your list of numbers grows it becomes more and more likely that ORing them together will provide all 1s , and I am not seeing how XORing them is going to give you desired results.

Comment: the reason i am not sorting them is that the group is very small (up to 7 numbers) and the routine is very performance sensitive.
that is why i am trying to find the fastest rule out check.

Comment: Have you considered threading the search?  If the list never changes you should be able to read the array from as many threads as you wish without stepping on toes - no mutex would be required since the data isn't changing.

Comment: A suggested by hivert, a boolean array could be fastest. For 32 bit numbers, you could use an array of bits stored in 528 mega bytes of memory. It would just take one indexed (by value >> 3) read to get the byte, then a test to see if any of the bits in the byte are set, so just two operations for a non-hit. If any of the bits are set, then you'd need test for a specific bit being set with a shift (shift by (value & 7)), and a boolean and (&).

Comment: @rcgldr Allocating 528 megabytes of zeroes, with only seven bits set in the whole thing, is a good way to kill performance through cache thrashing, and probably the slowest possible approach.

Comment: @rcgldr: A guess is that 528 megabyte of memory, being constantly accessed, would cause very bad cache behaviour.

Comment: >cache thrashing using large boolean array. Yes it would be slow, but it would be a normally two operation algoritm as requested by the original poster. The SIMD mthod as mentioned by Sneftel would probably be fastest.

Answer (score 5):

For only seven numbers, you should just do a brute force search through your set; it'll be faster than any other method. If your values are 16 bits or fewer, you can do it in a single SIMD equality test; if they're 32 bits, you can do it in two.

Comment: Sorting the set should still give marginal results as you can drop out of the search once you find a number greater than your search term.

Comment: @DanFarrell It's likely that an early-out would reduce performance because of branch misprediction stalls.

Comment: @ItayMarom Most good ideas related to doing things efficiently are platform-dependent.

Comment: Actually, your first answer (the one you've removed) has helped me find the solution : a simple bloom filter.
http://billmill.org/bloomfilter-tutorial/

Comment: I actually don't think a bloom filter is a good idea here. With the small number of elements in the set, evaluating the hash functions is likely to be more expensive than a simple search.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple hash function that maps your domain to a constant range (say `a.x mod b` or similar) and an array of `b` Booleans. If you are lucky/careful enough, you may end up with no hash collisions and an exact test.

Answer (score 0):

### Data Structuring

Let min be the minimum value of your target set.
Let max be the maximum value of your target set.

Let bset be a vector of bits, the size being the total number of bits required to hold max - min.

For each number x in the target set, let n = x - min.  Set the nth bit in the set.

### Predicate

For a given number x, let n = x - min, if the nth bit is set, it's a member.

The cost for each test should be, 1 subtraction, 2 bit shifts, an array access and one logical and.  You might be able to probabalistically shave off a lot more if your bit vector is represented by a set of either 32 bit or 64 bit values by first testing if the value is non zero before masking off the bit.

The cost for memory depends on the difference between max and min.

Depending on the size of the input set, I'd also be inclined to JIT compile a comparator for the numbers you have.  If you write a binary search on the fly, you're looking at worst case log2(n) comparisons, which is comparable to the binary vector for up to ~32 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If "static and beginning of time" means compile-time, you could use a switch.

```
bool inGroup(int i) {
switch(i) {
case X1: return true;
case X2: return true;
// ...
case X7: return true;
default: return false;
}
```

If the numbers are not widely distributed in the integer range, this will result in a jump-table. If the number range is widely distributed, you could compute an optimal hash function e.g. with gperf.

If the numbers are not compile-time constants, you should consider storing them in an array, sort it and use a binary search. Sorting needs to be done only once, and searching will need max. three comparisons.